# WordPress / CF7 - Customising the Contact Form 7 ajax loader gif, depending on location

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, loading-image

I am using the Contact Form 7 plugin on a web site, which has a contact form in the footer of every page and also a contact form in the main area of a dedicated Contact page.

I know how to customise the ajax loader gif in CF7...

`function my_wpcf7_ajax_loader () {
    return  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/my-loader-image.gif';
}
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_loader', 'my_wpcf7_ajax_loader');`

...but my problem is that I need to specify two different loader images - one for the footer form and one for the Contact page form. (The reason for this is because one form is on a white background and the other is on a red background, and despite experimenting with different [loader gifs](http://www.ajaxload.info/) I don't think it is possible to have a loader gif that looks good on both.)

Comment: have you got a link? you might be able to do this with css background.

Comment: Sure, here is the link: http://www.vegantuckbox.co.uk/contact-us/ . You can use FireBug to remove the `visibility` and `display` properties which will show the two loader images. The first (good) loader image is located in the DOM right after the "SEND MESSAGE" button. The other (bad) loader image is located in the DOM right after the "SUBMIT" button (in the footer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution: https://gist.github.com/tctc91/8271205

```
add_filter('wpcf7_ajax_loader', 'my_wpcf7_ajax_loader');

function my_wpcf7_ajax_loader () {
    return  network_home_url() . '/assets/themes/ips-helpdesk/images/ajax-loader.gif';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As loading image is an `img` element with `src` attribute, css methods will not be helpful.
It would be required to change `src` attribute of `img` tag through JavaScript and without modifying the core js of contact 7 form plugin (to allow plugin upgrades in future), I have come with following JavaScript solution to apply this change by bruteforce method.

```
(function($) {
    setInterval(function() {
        if(typeof $.fn.wpcf7InitForm != "undefined") {
            //Contact Form 7 is loaded and initialized
            $loaderImage = $("#wpcf7-f52-o2 img.ajax-loader"); // modify your selector accordingly
            if(!$loaderImage.data("pathChanged")) {
                $loaderImage.attr("src", "ALTERNATIVE_IMAGE_PATH");
                $loaderImage.data("pathChanged", true);
            }
        }
    }, 2000);
})(jQuery);
```

Though it may not be the best way, See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but I would prefer a PHP solution.

Comment: @ban-geoengineering, in that case you would need to change the core files of Contact Form 7 plugin, which is not recommended way, as the changes will be overwritten once plugin is upgraded.

Comment: See Denzorrr's answer, below - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32975785/1617737 - as there is a hook available.

Answer (score 0):

I read an article with a solid solution for your problem. They gave this solution:

```
    // Change the URL to the ajax-loader image
function change_wpcf7_ajax_loader($content) {
    if ( is_page('contact') ) {
        $string = $content;
        $pattern = '/(<img class="ajax-loader" style="visibility: hidden;" alt="ajax loader" src=")(.*)(" \/>)/i';
        $replacement = "$1".get_template_directory_uri()."/images/ajax-loader.gif$3";
        $content =  preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_wpcf7_ajax_loader', 100 );
```

link to the article [here](https://johansteen.se/blog/optimize-style-contact-form-7-wordpress/):

Comment: Cheers for that. Coincidentally, I just gave up on CF7 earlier today as it was causing big delays according to the pingdom speed test. :-/

Comment: I think the original code from my question, wrapped in `if (is_page('contact')) { ... }` would be a better solution - but it still doesn't solve the problem if I have two contact forms on the same page, each requiring a different spinner gif...

Answer (score 0):

Note: We're using a heavily modified twenty twenty theme and NONE of these solutions worked.  Tried them all.  Updated to latest version of plugin, still the same issue.  Can't disabled plugins one at a time and test by practical means because there are dozens and because we need the ones that we have.